# aws eventbridge api destination execution over time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

There is a lambda that runs for 5 to 10 minutes.
The API key requires authorization and its value.

I set api destination in eventbridge to do cron work once a day.
However, the Lambda is repeated.
When I checked the document, the maximum processing time of api destination was 5 seconds, so I think eventbridge tried it again.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html)

Instead of 5 seconds, I'm working on a Lambda that runs for 5 to 10 minutes
Is there another way(cron job) in aws?

Comment: In the EventBridge rule, do you have the Target Type set to "AWS Service" and the target set to the Lambda function? I would recommend following this guide to configure the EventBridge rule https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a Event Bridge Scheduler to trigger a lambda. If you look at the lambda configurations; there should be an option to add event scheduler as the trigger. You can configure it to run as needed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).